# Calculate the latitudes of a Gaussian Grid

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting, climate-models

I would like to calculate the latitude values of a [Gaussian Grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_grid) of a size of my choosing. Unfortunately, I didn't find a method or a formula to do so. Where can I find this information? Alternatively, is there a function publicly available that can do the job?

Comment: What do you mean by calculate? How are you setting the grid up? Latitude is one coordinate of the Gaussian Grid. It is set up like a grid in spherical coordinates.

Comment: The Gaussian grid of a specified size only has points at certain latitudes (as e.g. shown in the image of the linked Wikipedia article). I would like to calculate these latitude values.

Comment: HINT: NCL can do it if you can get the google search right. I mean there is a function in NCL to do this. :-) Heck if I am going to share it ;-)

Comment: @gansub, I looked it up. You are right! If you like you can post this as an answer and I will then accept it.

Comment: @Ethunxxx - if you are not happy with NCL then just download the source code and look at the method gaus and translate that into your favorite programming language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the NCL function [NCL gaus](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/Functions/Built-in/gaus.shtml) should be able to give you the solution you are looking for. From the API documentation you are requested to provide - the number of latitude points per hemisphere and you should get Gaussian latitudes and Gaussian weights.

Here is a code sample from their website

```
nlat = 64  ; for globe
gau_info = gaus(nlat/2)   ; divide by 2 to get "per hemisphere"
glat     = gau_info(:,0)  ; gaussian latitudes ( 1st dimension of gau_info)
gwgt     = gau_info(:,1)  ; gaussian weights   ( 2nd dimension of gau_info)
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want pure python

`conda install cdms2 -c conda-forge`

then in python:

`lats = cdms2.createGaussianAxis(128)`

you can also create a full lat/lon grid:

`grid = cdms2.createGaussianGrid(128)`